# Find datetime when maximum value reached again

Tags: r

I want to be able to find the next date when a maximum is reached again.

This is part of my plot. The maximum is the circle. I'd like to identify the point at which the same value is reached again in the curnve.

[image]

i.e. this point (yellow dot).

[image]

##### Data Frame

I have one data frame with:

1. loc: A column that has a site ID (there are 22 sites in total).
2. DateTime: A datetime column
3. mAODscale: A column of the line data.
4. maxDate: A column with 1 and NAs where the 1 represents the max value. I.e. the circle on the plot.

I would like to be able to make another column similar to the 'maxDate' column called 'maxDate2' with 1s representing the value when the max value has been reached again.

##### Sample Data

```
structure(list(loc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("B1", 
"B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "SSSI1", "SSSI2", "SSSI3", 
"CM1", "CM2", "CM3", "CM4", "CM7", "CM8", "CM9", "CM11", "Crose 1", 
"Crose 2", "Crose 3"), class = "factor"), DateTime = structure(c(1646092800, 
1646179200, 1646265600, 1646352000, 1646438400, 1646524800), tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), mAODscale = c(-0.015423214285704, -0.0143773809523822, 
-0.013344047619043, -0.0147440476190468, -0.01465238095237, -0.0153232142857149
), maxDate = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000166921a9910>)
```

##### Desired Output Example

Note: I've made up this data

[image]

data for the above dataframe

```
structure(list(Loc = c("B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", 
"B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"), DateTime = c("12/05/2022", "13/05/2022", 
"14/05/2022", "15/05/2022", "16/05/2022", "17/05/2022", "12/05/2022", 
"13/05/2022", "14/05/2022", "15/05/2022", "16/05/2022", "17/05/2022"
), mAODscale = c(0.6, 0.73, 0.55, 0.43, 0.88, 0.15, 0.56, 0.6, 
0.01, 0.94, 0.34, 0.23), maxDate = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), maxDate2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

##### Edits:

Current code:
I've added in the slice to remove data before the first maxDate.

```
    maxval2 <- scaleDrought %>%
      group_by(loc) %>% 
      slice(which.max(maxDate==1) : n()) %>%
      mutate(maxDate2 = if_else((maxDate != 1 & mAODscale == max(mAODscale)), 1, 0)) %>% 
      ungroup()
```

Resulting plotted data:

The diamond is the second max date. But its in a different place from where it should be. i.e. the yellow dot.

[image]

Comment: this is how I understand it: ````df$maxDate2 <- NA; df$maxDate2[df$mAODscale[df$maxDate==1]] <- 1````

Comment: @efz I don't think you've included all of your message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted TarJae's answer:

```
maxval2 <- scaleDrought %>%
  group_by(loc) %>% 
  slice(which.max(maxDate==1) : n()) %>%
  mutate(maxDate2 = if_else((maxDate != 1 & mAODscale >= mAODscale[1]), 1, 0)) %>% 
  distinct(maxDate2, .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Perfect!. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  group_by(Loc) %>% 
  mutate(maxDate2 = if_else(maxDate != 1 & mAODscale == max(mAODscale), 1, 0)) %>% 
  ungroup()

     Loc   DateTime   mAODscale maxDate maxDate2
   <chr> <chr>          <dbl>   <int>    <dbl>
 1 B1    12/05/2022      0.6        0        0
 2 B1    13/05/2022      0.73       1        0
 3 B1    14/05/2022      0.55       0        0
 4 B1    15/05/2022      0.43       0        0
 5 B1    16/05/2022      0.88       0        1
 6 B1    17/05/2022      0.15       0        0
 7 B2    12/05/2022      0.56       0        0
 8 B2    13/05/2022      0.6        1        0
 9 B2    14/05/2022      0.01       0        0
10 B2    15/05/2022      0.94       0        1
11 B2    16/05/2022      0.34       0        0
12 B2    17/05/2022      0.23       0        0
```

Comment: This is close. But I need it to be the instance at which it first crosses the max value. Probably haven't quite provided the best example data. But If the first location values were: 0.6, 0.73,0.55,0.74, 0.88, and 0.15. I want the 1 in the corresponding row for 0.74 rather than 0.88. I also need it not to be a value before the original max date.